# How to stick div Banner ("50% off of our products") to Navbar which is right above it?

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, bootstrap-5, react-fullstack

BOOSTRAP:
How to stick div Banner ("50% off of our products") to Navbar which is right above it ?

So structure is following:

```
<NavBar>
</NavBar>

<div>
    <span>Discount: 50% off of our products </span
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To stick the div banner with the discount offer to the navbar, you can use Bootstrap's built-in classes and CSS properties.

First, wrap both the navbar and the discount banner inside a container div with a class of "container-fluid". This class will create a full-width container that spans the entire width of the viewport.

Next, add a class of "fixed-top" to the navbar. This will make the navbar fixed at the top of the screen as the user scrolls.

To position the discount banner right below the navbar, add a class of "mt-5" to the div that contains the discount offer. This will add a top margin of 5 units to the div, pushing it down below the navbar.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
<!-- navbar content -->
</nav>
<div class="mt-5">
    <span>Discount: 50% off of our products</span>
  </div>
</div>
```